# PostgreSQL copy permissions

Tags: postgresql

I'm using pgadmin to copy a csv file into the database.

this worked fine a million times until today. I get the following error

Could not open file "/path.csv" for reading: permission denied

I poked around google, and some of the suggestions were to disable SELinux which i don't plan on doing, since my code worked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are the permissions on the path.csv file? Perhaps the file was created by a different user than usual and you don't have read permission on it. Sure sounds like a simple file permissions issue and not a DB issue.

Comment: You're right, for some reason, it's a different user that owns it. How stupid of me !

Comment: happens to all of us, far too often ;-)